# Phantom TFS workspace will not let me map to another workspace?

Tags: tfs, workspace

I type this command:  tf workspaces into a command line and it tells me there are no workspaces on the machine. I then try the same command on the server, nothing. So I go into Visual Studio 2010 and create a new workspace and try to map the TFS path to my local path. I then get an error that the mapping already exists in another workspace. But I cannot find that workspace on my local or on the tfs server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run `tf workspaces /remove:*` to clear out your local cache of workspaces. See [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/09/12/path-is-already-mapped-in-workspace.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I found this after I wrote it, but I give you the props! I also used this: http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just came across this issue on a Linux machine running TEE (Team Explorer Everywhere).  Running "tf workspaces -remove:*" didn't work, because it said there were no workspaces in the cache.

The user was trying to create a new workspace, which worked, but when he tried to map folders, it told him it didn't exist.
When he ran "tf workspaces" on the machine and when I looked in TFS Sidekicks on the server itself, it didn't show any workspaces for him on the Linux box.
If he tried to create the workspace again, it told him that it already existed, but every time he tried to map, he was told it didn't.

We could see the workspace from the tf command line if I did "tf workspaces /owner:", and it required me to run "tf workspace /delete ;" from the command line to get rid of it.
Once we did that, he was able to create it again and everything worked properly.
No idea why that happened, but figured I'd post my answer here just in case someone else comes across a similar issue in the future.